# python ImportError: No module named cy_unity graphlab

Tags: python-2.7, graphlab

I am new to python and I am trying to work on a project with deep learning and want to use graphlab library. I use sublime text for coding on windows 10. My code is only this line:

`import graphlab`

I get this error msg:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test.py", line 1, in

```
import graphlab
```

File "graphlab__init__.py", line 59, in

```
from graphlab.data_structures.sgraph import Vertex, Edge
```

File "graphlab\data_structures__init__.py", line 25, in

```
from . import sframe
```

File "graphlab\data_structures\sframe.py", line 19, in

```
from ..connect import main as glconnect
```

File "graphlab\connect\main.py", line 26, in

```
from ..cython.cy_unity import UnityGlobalProxy
```

ImportError: No module named cy_unity

Comment: May I know, from where you install `graphlab`?

Comment: https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made a mistake when installing, i re-installed and it worked fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try using `graphlab.get_dependencies()` in your interpreter.